# Add class with jQuery for second columns of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>ccc</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>ccc</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>ccc</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>ccc</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>ccc</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
</table>

table td {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.red {
   background-color: red;
}
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/zCduV/1/

How can i add class .red with jQuery for second column in this table (in this example this is there where in td is ccc)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This maybe?

```
// selects both table header and table data cells from the second column of the table
$('table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2)').addClass('red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tdTkQ/

Comment: @Jaikrat If I get what you mean, you simply leave the th bit out. e.g.: `$('table td:nth-child(2)').addClass('red');`

Comment: Thanks @DeadlyKipper.... I implemented it using other way ....Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 11):

By using the jQuery nth-child selector:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('red');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jQuery [nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). This is what you are looking for.

```
 $('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('red');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('red');
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpjzj/) of this solution.

Comment: Sorry when I give the answer @SeanNieuwoudt has already given.